# How to use preg_match() to instead of eregi()?

Tags: php

I'm a php beginner, I want to use preg_match() to instead of eregi() in the following code, but I don't know how to do that.

```
if (!eregi(“^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$”, trim($_POST['email']))) {
```

I simply replace eregi to preg_match, but I got php error "PHP Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter ‘^’ found"

How can I fix it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Btw, change those curly quotes when you do convert it `“ ”`

Comment: (The link is among the duplicates that *did come up* when you wrote your question title.)